# Число из строки с мусором в Python

Tags: python

Есть строка: "228 1337.228 ваш отец"
Нужно получить float: 2281337.228

как это сделать?

Comment: То есть мы должны выводить всегда float, а затем склеивать все числовые значения в число типа float, которое и нужно вывести? Если нет, можете описать само задание из источника?

Comment: Нужно просто все цифры, которые есть в строке получать в виде одного float

Comment: Может ли быть две или более десятичных точек?

Answer (score 4):

Трудно понять что вы считаете мусором, а что числом. Код ниже выбрасывает из строки всё кроме цифр и точки. Из остатка делает вещественное число:

```
s = '228 1337.228 ваш отец'
print(float(''.join(c for c in s if c in '.0123456789')))
```